# PHP- Search for string in an array, in a loop

Tags: php, regex

What I would like to do is search a file containing; multiple space delimited words and characters, on multiple lines, using preg_grep, containing a certain string, and store as a variable. I would like to then "for loop" through those matched lines, and search within for yet another string.

For sake of example, assume `$c` contains all the lines that match variable `$a` (in an Array?), in the file `$o`, and returns 9 lines that contain that variable.  How

```
$c = preg_grep("/\b$a\b/", $o);
```

So I set `$max = sizeof($c)`

```
$max = sizeof($c);     // In this example contains 9
```

Here I try to loop through `$c` to find variable `$b`, and would like to print that line that matches

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    $st = preg_grep("/\b$b\b/", $c);
    echo implode($st, ' ');
}
```

In the first search if I echo `implode($c, ' ')`, I get all 9 values displayed as one solid string. It seems though using the same technique after my loop, I am not getting the result I want, which is a single line resulting from matching both variables.

Additionally, I know there may be much easier ways to accomplish this, but following this example, Where am I making a mistake(s).

*EDIT*
If it helps, a sample of the text file:

```
13 04000 Atlanta city GA 394017 +33.762900 -08.4422592
13 56000 North Atlanta CDP PA 27812 0000000147 +33.862550
```

Where $c = preg_grep("/\b$a\b/", $o); would match both lines
And ideally, if $b= PA, the second preg_grep would yeild:

```
13 56000 North Atlanta CDP PA 27812 0000000147 +33.862550
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$o` is an array of lines:

```
$result = preg_grep("/\b$b\b/", preg_grep("/\b$a\b/", $o));
echo implode(" ", $result);
```

This will give an array of elements from `$o` that match both `$a` and `$b`.